# Popen can find the existing tool

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to run the following;

```
def conn(ad_group):
    result = Popen(["sudo -S /opt/quest/bin/vastool", "-u host/ attrs 'AD_GROUP_NAME' | grep member"], stdout=PIPE)
    return result.stdout
```

on a RedHat machine in a python script but I'm getting `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sudo -S /opt/quest/bin/vastool'`

I can run the command(`sudo -S /opt/quest/bin/vastool -u host/ attrs 'AD_GROUP_NAME' | grep member`) at the command line without a problem.

I'm sure I've messed up something in the function but I need an other set of eyes.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the entire command a single string, and use the `shell=True` option because you're using a shell pipeline.

```
result = Popen("sudo -S /opt/quest/bin/vastool -u host/ attrs 'AD_GROUP_NAME' | grep member", stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: That did the job. Thank you